# Live video duration/length limit

Tags: youtube, stream, streaming

I'm not sure if I choose Stack correct for this question, but it is my last chance.

If I want to live stream video for about 8 hours, it will be saved on Youtube? I have no time to try this, so please, help me. I found some info about max length of video (128GB) but nothing about duration.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about (current) Youtube limitations, not programming related

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know nothing about 8 hours, but at least 6h in 720p is ok (tested).